# twitter connect and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, oauth

I am reading this tutorial: http://blog.dhavalparikh.co.in/2009/06/step-by-step-twitter-oauth-integration-with-rails/

OK, first redirect to twitter connect page. When I allow the connection, twitter redirect to https://twitter.com/oauth/authorize with a code for connect but this must redirect to a action which connect and create a new user in my db.

SO which could be the problem? How i must config the twitter application callback url and app url for localhost.

please i need this answer

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is: Twitter send the token information via post. SO i receive the token by params.
Also there is a problem with oauth 0.4.
I am using oauth 0.3.4 because work in the correct form when twitter try redirect to callback url.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really answer your question but is a nicer way to do this.
[Omniauth](http://github.com/intridea/omniauth) is a nice gem for rails that makes it very easy to offer twitter, facebook etc. login.

A good intro to this was created by [Ryan Bates of Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1).